# Receiving a blank page with no error on submitting php contact form

Tags: php, mailgun

I made a simple Contact us form and it worked perfectly fine. But now, after adding a mailgun script for sending and receiving emails it is showing me nothing but a blank page .

**Script:**

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Mailgun\Mailgun;
$mailgun = new Mailgun('key-41616099541fe1b0187e7cd970127240', new \Http\Adapter\Guzzle6\Client());

$mgClient = new Mailgun('key-41616099');
$domain = "sandbox614b.mailgun.org";

$from = 'Demo contact form <test@example.com >';
$to = 'Demo contact form <test@example.com>';
$name = $_POST['name'];
$subject =  $_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$fields = array('name' => 'Name', 'email' => 'Email', 'phone' => 'Phone', 'subject' => 'Subject', 'message' => 'Message'); 

$okMessage = 'Contact form successfully submitted. Thank you, I will get back to you soon!';

$errorMessage = 'There was an error while submitting the form. Please try again later';

// if you are not debugging and don't need error reporting, turn this off by error_reporting(0);
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
try
{
    if(count($_POST) == 0) throw new \Exception('Form is empty');

    $content = "You have a new message from your contact form";
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) 
    {
        if (isset($fields[$key]))
            {
            $content .= "$fields[$key]: $value\n";

    //recaptcha-response
    $recaptcha_secret = "6LfK7ygUAAAAAIYzE6mbqdxbmuroi4gJWqdIpmBu";
    $response = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".$recaptcha_secret."&response=".$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);
    $response = json_decode($response, true);

# Make the call to the client.
$result = $mgClient->sendMessage("$domain",
          array('from'    => 'Mailgun Sandbox <postmaster@sandbox614b.mailgun.org>',
                'to'      => 'Nami <nami19@gmail.com>',
                'subject' => 'Hello Nami',
                'text'    => 'Congratulations Nami, you just sent an email with Mailgun!  You are truly awesome! '));

      echo "Form Submit Successfully.";
        } else {
        echo "You are a robot";
        }
    }
}
   catch (\Exception $e)
{
    $responseArray = array('type' => 'danger', 'message' => $errorMessage);
}

?>
```

What could I be possibly doing wrong?

Comment: Check if there's anything in your error logs

Comment: The last Error log I received was  this: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE)  in line 68, but I did checked the braces and figured the error . And now when I run the form it shows blank page.

Answer (score 0):

To be frank, it looks like a lot has gone wrong with that code. Unless of course there is code you haven't posted, most of that code doesn't appear to actually do anything or is otherwise connected to anything. What you've posted is only 57 lines of code, so line 68 doesn't exist so far as I am concerned (in regards to your other comment).

You've got a syntax error in your **sendMessage()** function, as well as where you define your **$content** variable. You are declaring **$mailgun** as a class but don't actually use it anywhere. Your **forEach()** loop iterates through each post value and tries to send an email, which in your case, I don't believe is the goal. Your if statement within that for loop will always return true and as such, there is no point in using it. These are just the things that immediately stick out to me.

Based on what you've posted, this is the only code that appears to have logical relevance:

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Mailgun\Mailgun;

$mgClient = new Mailgun('key-41616099');
$domain = "sandbox614b.mailgun.org";

$name = $_POST['name'];
$subject =  $_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$errorMessage = 'There was an error while submitting the form. Please try again later';

// if you are not debugging and don't need error reporting, turn this off by error_reporting(0);
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);

try {

    if(count($_POST) == 0) {

        throw new \Exception('Form is empty');

    }

    $data = array(
        'from'    => "Mailgun Sandbox <postmaster@sandbox614b.mailgun.org>",
        'to'      => "Nami <nami19@gmail.com>",
        'subject' => $subject,
        'text'    => "Congratulations ".$name.",\n".$message
    );

    # Make the call to the client.
    $result = $mgClient->sendMessage($domain, $data);

    echo "Form Submit Successfully.";

}

catch (\Exception $e) {

    $responseArray = array('type' => 'danger', 'message' => $errorMessage);

}

?>
```

I suggest you compare the two and spot some of the key differences to start.

Namita, this is a wonderful community full of those who wish to help you. However, your question is too general. It looks as though you've pasted bits and pieces from random places without much thought to what the code does. Moreover, and more importantly, you haven't provided us with an actual error of any kind nor anything you've done to try and fix the issue, let alone even identify the issue.

I recommend you take a look at the MailGun documentation which you can find here: https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/user_manual.html

Be sure to choose "PHP" from the bar at the top so as to see PHP code examples.